# Notation of the domain of a function.

Tags: functions, notation

[image]

Is the domain of a function always denoted by X? Because here it seems that X is just the codomain. I don't understand why k would have to be in the domain of f.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this is part of a longer argument---perhaps there is some context in the previous paragraphs that might help to understand what is going on?

Comment: There isn't really much context that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domains and codomains of functions can be *any* set, represented by any letter (or combination of letters, or symbol, or combination of symbols) that we like.  In the example you cite, context indicates that $k$ must be an element of the codomain, thus $X$ must be the codomain.

Comment: Clear answer to my question, thanks you very much.